# MaterialDesignInXaml how to implement scroll control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, material-design-in-xaml

Using WPF and the material design in xaml package, how can I implement a very tall column of options, such that you can scroll until the option you want aligns with a mark to select it. The very tall column of options won't fit on the screen, so elements need to appear into the screen and then disappear as they are scrolled. This would look kind of like a slot machine. Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve scrolling by placing your elements inside a [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-overview).